# PIL to numpy and PIL to tensor is different

Tags: numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library, tensor

I have image and sum torch tensor and numpy array is diffrent, why?
How to torch_img.sum() = numpy_float_img.sum()?

```
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms as T

# Read image with PIL
img = Image.open(img_path).resize((224,224))

torch_img = T.ToTensor()(img)
numpy_img = np.asarray(img)
numpy_img_float = np.asarray(img).astype(np.float32)

print(torch_img.sum(), numpy_img.sum(), numpy_img_float.sum())
->56914.496, 14513196, 14513196.0
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how `torch_img` is in the `[0,1]` range while `numpy_img` and `numpy_img_float` are both in the `[0, 255]` range. Looking at the documentation for [`torchvision.transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor), if the provided input is a `PIL` image, then the values will be mapped to `[0, 1]`. In contrast, `numpy.array` will have the values remain in the `[0, 255]` range.

Other than that the small variations in results are caused by different floating-point precisions.